# Standard form in TeX?

Tags: math-mode

How do I write x10 to the power of something within an equation?

At the moment I'm using `y \times 10^x`, but it gets slightly confusing if I have a long line of numbers that I'm multiplying together.

This the equation I have now:

```
g = \frac{6.67 \times 10^{-11} \times 6 \times 10^{24}}{6400010^2}
```

Which produces the output:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) May you expand your question showing an example of what you have to do?

Comment: How does it look with parentheses: (a x 10^b) x (c x 10^d)?

Comment: Yes that does improve the clarity, but it's a workaround not a fix. :(

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you need to typeset actual numbers (and not symbols as in your example), you could use the `\num` macro provided by `siunitx`. It allows you to type `\num{2e3}` to output [image], both in math and in text mode.

When multiplying numbers in exponential form, you could reduce the spacing within the numbers, using `tight-spacing=true`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\sisetup{tight-spacing=true}
\[
g = \frac{\num{6.67e-11} \times \num{6e24}}{6400010^2}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm talking about inside equations, sorry I didn't mention that in the question first time!

Comment: @ToddDavies: Ah, okay, I think now I understand your problem. The repeated use of `\times` is confusing for the reader. Hm...

Comment: Yes that's right, is there a way of maybe I could wrap the x10 in a \small{}...

Comment: This is the cleanest solution, it appeals to the programmer in me! Thanks Jack!

Comment: I think I would write the middle `\times` as a `\cdot`.

Comment: @Manuel: Mathematically, all the operations are just multiplications, so I don't think it's a good idea to use different symbols for the same thing. I think the choice of whether to use a dot or a cross for multiplication of single numbers is largely a cultural one (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication#Notation_and_terminology), but one should be consistent.

Comment: @Jake I'm not sure, but I think that is wrong to use `2 \cdot 10^{-3}`. When using scientific notation I've always seen `2 \times 10^{-3}`. That's why I don't worry to mix them. But may be I'm wrong. For me this is right, and I don't feel inconsistent (because `\times` is just notation): `\num{33e-55} \cdot \num{36e1} \cdot \num{27e-2}`. (PS: I delete the other comment)

Comment: @Manuel: I think in cultures where a comma is used as a decimal separator, a dot is frequently used for multiplications, including in scientific notation (e.g. in German, see http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wissenschaftliche_Notation). In English, this is avoided because of the danger of confusion with the period decimal separator, so a cross is used for everything (except scalar products of matrices, of course, but that's a different matter).

Comment: Ok, didn't know about that.

Comment: Use of a multiplication dot isn't even uncommon in certain places which speak English, at least among physicists and mathematicians. If the decimal point is not vertically centred, it is usually easy to distinguish from a multiplication dot. In those cases where there is risk of ambiguity, parentheses or spacing around the multiplication are often used. Because in context, it is easier to tell a centred dot from a decimal point, than a multiplication cross from the letter x.

Comment: Can we just use: `\num{24}` for 10^24?

Answer (score 9):

I know many will disagree with the following but nonetheless this what I used to use:

```
\newcommand{\sn}[2]{\ensuremath{{#1}\times 10^{#2}}}
```

And I use it like this: `\sn{y}{x}`. Here is an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\sn}[2]{\ensuremath{{#1}\times 10^{#2}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
(\sn{2.25}{\textcolor{Cerulean}{4}})(\sn{7.5}{\textcolor{OrangeRed}{6}})    &= \sn{(2.25)(7.5)}{\textcolor{Cerulean}{4}+\textcolor{OrangeRed}{6}}\\
                                   &= \sn{16.875}{10}\\
                                   &= \sn{1.6875}{11}\\
                                   &= \sn{1.7}{11} \quad(\text{2 s.f.})
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use `{\times}` instead of `\times`, the former does not add the additional spaces

Comment: Please always provide a complete answer with reference or using (some of) OP's code.